# OpenAI SDK v1.0 API error: "AttributeError: 'OpenAI' object has no attribute 'Completion'"

Tags: openai-api, gpt-3

So I've got some ganky code for writing a business plan, and it was working but is dead now as of `v1.0`, I can't work out how to properly re-code it without `AttributeError: 'OpenAI' object has no attribute 'Completion'` error occurring. Anyone able to help?

```
# Function to generate text for each section using OpenAI's API
def generate_text_for_section(section_name, user_input):
response = openai.Completion.create(
    model="text-davinci-003",
    prompt=f"Write a detailed description for a business plan section titled '{section_name}'. Project idea: {user_input}.",
    max_tokens=500
)
return response.choices[0].text.strip()
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem

**The method name you're trying to use doesn't work with the OpenAI Python SDK version `1.0.0` or newer.**

The old SDK (i.e., version `0.28`) works with the following method name:

```
client.Completion.create
```

The new SDK (i.e., version `1.0.0` or newer) works with the following method name:

```
client.completions.create
```

*Note: Be careful because the API is case-sensitive (i.e., `client.Completions.create` will not work with the new SDK version).*

#### Solution

Try this:

```
import os
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI()
OpenAI.api_key = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')

completion = client.completions.create(
  model="gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct",
  prompt="Say this is a test",
  max_tokens=7,
  temperature=0
)

print(completion.choices[0].text)
```